# Is this undefined behavior or a false positive warning?

Tags: c++, constructor, undefined-behavior, clang++

Consider the following code:

```
class A {
private:
  int a;

public:
  A(int a) : a(a) { }
};

class B : public A {
private:
  int b;

  bool init() {
    b = 0;
    return true;
  }

public:
  // init() is a hack to initialize b before A()
  // B() : b(0), A(b) {} yields -Wreorder
  // B() : A((b = 0)) {} no warning (but this one doesn't work so well with non-pod (pointer) types)
  B() : A(init() ? b : 0) {}
};
```

Now trying to compile this code with clang...

```
$ clang++ test.cpp -fsyntax-only
test.cpp:19:20: warning: field 'b' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
B() : A(init() ? b : 0) {}
                 ^
1 warning generated.
```

GCC does not print any warnings, not even with `-Wall -Wextra` and `-pedantic`.

Comment: Why is `B::init` returning a constant value?  I suggest declaring it return `void`.  No point in having a function that returns a constant value that is not determined by the contents inside the function.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: It's a stripped down example from my real code, `(void) a` was just an attempt to silence `-Wunused-private-field`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - based on the abstract nature of this example, it's reasonably safe to assume `B::init` is returning a constant is part of creating a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: _"`init() is a hack to initialize b before A()`"_ Unfortunately it does no such thing!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's undefined behavior. According to [class.base.init]:

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>   — First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class (1.8), virtual base classes ...
>   — Then, **direct base classes are initialized** in declaration order as they appear in the base-specifier-list
>   (regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
>   — Then, **non-static data members are initialized** in the order they were declared in the class definition
>   (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).

`b` won't have been initialized by the time that the `A` base class is initialized. The assignment `b = 0` is itself undefined behavior for the same reason - `b` hadn't been initialized yet when that is called. Its default constructor would still be called after `A`'s constructor.

If you want ensure that `b` is initialized first, the typical approach is the [base-from-member idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Base-from-Member):

```
struct B_member {
    int b;
    B_member() : b(0) { }
};

class B : public B_member, public A 
{
public:
    B() : A(b)  // B_member gets initialized first, which initializes b
                // then A gets initialized using 'b'. No UB here.
    { };
};
```

Comment: This would make sense as an answer for non-POD members, but consider that `int main() { int a; a = 1; }` is perfectly valid even though `a` has never been initialised. For POD types, assignment can be a valid alternative to initialisation.

Comment: @hvd `int a;` still default-initializes `a`.  But yes, this would definitely be more of a problem for non-PODs.

Comment: @Barry default-initialization is not initializing scalars. The object is deemed uninitialized, having indeterminate value.

Comment: @Barry If you want to say that by some logic that I can't quite understand, default initialisation is meaningful even when it doesn't do anything, then consider `int *p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)); if (p) *p = 3;`. Now there has been no initialisation at all, not even default initialisation.

Comment: @hvd What does this have to do with PODs, specifically? AFAICS The reason that the behavior is well-defined is that the initialization associated with `b` is vacuous, making it alive after storage is acquired. This, in fact, is true for e.g. any class with a trivial default constructor that is used in this scenario, ones that are not necessarily POD-classes.

Comment: @Columbo It's a bit of an over-simplification on my part. Generally speaking, assignment to non-trivially-copyable types (which includes all non-POD types) calls some type's `operator=` member function, and calling a member function on an object requires that object to already be initialised. (Actually, strictly speaking, this is the case even for POD class types, so your interpretation gives more desirable results. Will check to see if I can find what the standard actually says.)

Comment: Are you suggesting it's only UB if `b` has non-trivial initialization? That case is definitely UB at least since `b`'s lifetime won't have even begun yet. But is it only that case?

Comment: @Barry I'm only suggesting that if it's UB, it's UB for another reason than what you give in your answer. I don't really know if it is defined, I'm trying to figure that out myself too. Your comment gives a reasonable alternative interpretation for why it's UB: the access to a member of the `B` object is subject to some restrictions when the `B` object is not wholly constructed yet. Those restrictions may disallow the use of `b`.

Comment: @hvd Looks like Columbo found the better quote.

Comment: @Columbo I'm tempted to agree with you now: the lifetime of an object with trivial initialisation begins as soon as the storage is obtained, per 3.8, so even something like `struct S { int i; void f(int j) { i = j; } }; S *s = (S *) malloc(sizeof *s); if (s) s->f(1); }` should be valid.

Answer (score 6):

In either case, calling a member function before base classes are initialized invokes undefined behavior. §12.6.2/16:

> Member functions (including virtual member functions, 10.3) can be
>   called for an object under construction. Similarly, an object under
>   construction can be the operand of the `typeid` operator (5.2.8) or of a
>   `dynamic_cast` (5.2.7). **However, if these operations are performed in a
>   *ctor-initializer* (or in a function called directly or indirectly from a *ctor-initializer*) before all the *mem-initializers* for
>   base classes have completed, the result of the operation is
>   undefined.** [ Example:
>
> ```
> class A {
> public:
>   A(int);
> };
>
> class B : public A {
>   int j;
> public:
>   int f();
>   B() : A(f()),  // undefined: calls member function
>                  // but base A not yet initialized
>
>   j(f()) { }    // well-defined: bases are all initialized
> };
> ```

However, the access of and assignment to `b` itself is fine, since it has vacuous initialization and its lifetime starts as soon as storage is acquired for it (which happened long before the constructor call started). Hence

```
class B : public A {
private:
  int b;

public:
  B() : A(b=0) {}
};
```

is well-defined.

Comment: For what types is such access well-defined?

Comment: @Barry That is not depending upon the type alone, but the initialization in each particular case. §3.8 mandates that an objects lifetime begins after storage for it was allocated, and after its non-vacuous initialization was performed - *if any* (which is not the case here). Thus the validity of an access entirely depends on the initialization used in each case: If e.g. your object will have its trivial default constructor "called", assigning sth. to it before that constructor is "called" is fine.

Comment: So for members with trivial default constructors, which do not later appear in the mem-initializer?

Comment: @Barry .. and don't have a NSDMI. :) (And are not initialized by a target constructor.) </super-nitpick>